# How to create Conditional Xpath statement?

Tags: xml, xpath, selectnodes

I want to select xml node with conditional Xpath like-

```
xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("if (ns:substanceAdministration/ns:consumable/@typeCode == UNK) then evaluateThisXpath else evaluateOtherXpath")
```

my concern is-

```
<drugID code="UNK">
    <sub code="2232" />
</drugID>
```

**If @code of parent node is UNK then only it should take @code value of child node otherwise take parent @code value.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(drugID[@code='UNK']/sub)|(drugID[@code<>'UNK')
```

It is Xpath pseudocode, change it to your library language

Answer (score 6):

**Use**:

```
drugId[@code = 'UNK']/sub/@code | drugId/@code[not(. = 'UNK')]
```

which could be "abbreviated":

```
(drugId[@code = 'UNK']/sub | drugId[not(@code = 'UNK')])/@code
```